# Reading a .txt File and updating Java Bean Objects

Tags: java, string, file-io

I have the following file in .txt format

---

```
*XXX=017
*tag=016
*foci
String value
*XXX=018
*tag=024
*foci
*listname   
*XXX=018
*tag=024
*foci
String value
String value
String value
```

---

Here as we can see we have some predefined tags, and for each tag some value is associated with it.

Now each `*XXX` marks the beginning for an object to be updated. The object will store the values like 018, 024, String value associated with *foci or list value. Then again it will move to next `*XXX`.

I have created bean objects and also reading the file. But as there are no specification on how many lines will be available after the *foci tag, it is difficult to group the objects correctly. Can any one give any suggestion that how to differentiate each object or How to determine that we have reached end of `*foci` tag data or end of `*XXX` tag data.

Thanks

Comment: i think you should read lines until you get a * and store it into a buffer

Comment: pattern matching helped me. Thanks a lot for all of your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Java Properties instead of reading from the .txt files.

```
1.*XXX=017
1.*tag=016
1.*foci
2.*XXX=018
2.*tag=024
2.*foci *listname
```

numbers can be used to group the set of inputs together and can be appended into the key value while fetching the property from the properties.

Comment: properties file will not suitable as this is a one time activity to read and update DB. Thanks

Comment: Even though its a one time activity its better to use property file as Java has inbuilt capability to read it. Also we dont have to take the trouble of reading it using streams